# Misinterpreting a Phrase

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> Let $R$ be the collection of sequences $(a_1,a_2,...)$ of integers $a_1$, $a_2$,..., **where all but finitely many of the $a_i$ are $0$**. Prove that $R$ is a ring under componentwise addition and multiplication which does not have an identity.

I construed this phrase as, "$a_i \neq 0$ for finitely many $i \in \mathbb{N}$. If this is the case, how does $R$ form a ring? It doesn't seem to be closed under multiplication, for consider $(1,0,0,...)$ and $(0,1,0,...)$. Clearly their product does not contain any nonzero integers; i.e., the condition $a_i \neq 0$ for finitely many $i$" is not satisfied.

So, what is the correct interpretation of the phrase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zero is a finite cardinal, so $(0,0,\ldots) \in R$.

That is, all but a finite number of $a_i$ in that collection are $0$; that finite number happens, in fact, to be zero.

Comment: So, if I am understanding you correctly, the phrase should be taken to mean the infinite tuple contains a finite number of zeros?

Comment: No, the phrase is meant to say there are a finite number of non-zeros.